# Syntax error in SQL Insert Join Left command

Tags: sql, insert, sql-server-2012

I have an error in my SQL and no idea what i ve done wrong. maybe you guys can help me :)

```
conString = "INSERT INTO MUB_" & Searchterm(i1) & "_" & Tabellenname(0) & _
                " (" & dtTabelle1Columns & ")" & _
                " SELECT *" & _
                " FROM MUB_TEMP_" & Tabellenname(0) & " Temp" & _
                " LEFT JOIN MUB_" & Searchterm(i1) & "_" & Tabellenname(0) & " MUB" & _ 
                 " ON (MUB.[CurveId] = Temp.[CurveId] AND" & _ 
                 " MUB.[CycleDate] = Temp.[CycleDate])" & _
                 " WHERE (MUB.[CurveId] IS NULL AND MUB.[CycleDate] IS NULL);"
```

Error message: incorrect Syntax near ")"... i know the problem is related to my WHERE statement (when i remove the ( ) then it tells me incorrect syntax near WHERE) but i cant figure out why.

Thanks a lot for your support!!

Best 
Jonas

Comment: Edit your question and include the string *after* variable substitution and tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: You have missed spaces at start of strings on last three rows ("ON...") :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server requires table aliases on subqueries.  You can try:

```
            ") t WHERE (" & SQLString_2 & ");"
```

Comment: thanks :) what do you mean by "t"? Do you mean the table alias TEMP?

Comment: `t` is a table alias and it is a basic part of the SQL language.  It is an abbreviation for table names that can be used throughout a query.